# Catching exception from boost::asio::io_service::work running as a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I have my application main loop control where I do start a thread to handle asio work as follows:

```
void AsioThread::Run()
{
    try
    {
        /*
         * Start the working thread to io_service.run()
         */
        boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
        t.detach();

        while (true)
        {

            // Process stuff related to protocol, calling 
            // connect_async, send_async and receive_async
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &ex)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR IN FTP PROTOCOL: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "UNKNOWN EXCEPTION." << std::endl;
    }
```

During the async operation, the handlers are called and sometimes I do throw exception on those handlers, like:

```
void AsioThread::ReceiveDataHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTransferred)
{
        std::cout << "Receive data handler called. " << bytesTransferred << " bytes received." << std::endl;

        if (errorCode)
        {
            std::cout << "Error receiving data from server." << std::endl;
        }

        rxBufferSize = bytesTransferred;

        /* 
         * Check for response
         */
        std::string msg(rxBuffer);
        if (msg.substr(0, 3) != "220")
               throw std::runtime_error("Error connecting to FTP Server");
    }
```

My problem is that the exception thrown inside the async handler (`AsioThread::ReceiveDataHandler`) is not catched by the main processing loop `try...catch` block in `AsioThread::Run`. Naturally this happens because the working thread `t` is on another thread, detached, and at runtime that leads to an execution error.

How can I receive exceptions from the detached `boost::asio::io_service::work` thread ? How can I structure my code to make this logic work ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why do you have a separate <code>while (true)</code> event loop? You can just use the asio event loop to do everything? And in that case join the thread. If it can run out of work, create an io_service::work object.

Comment: I need the event loop because it works as a state processor for the procotol logic... Cannot make without it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, but generally protocol state is handled in the asynchronous callbacks. There is no need to have a separate event loop for this. E.g in the callback after async_connect you would be connected, etc. The event handlers start the next asynchronous action e.g. the async_connect handler could also start the reads and writes.

Comment: Yes, this is what is being done, but this whole logic runs called from a client Class that sends and receives command to maon loop, like Connect, SendFile, etc... That's whyvI do have a main loop to receive those messages... Like a command control concept where the protocolo is embedded...

Comment: Why does the exception need to be propagated to `AsioThread::Run()`?  Is it to only exit from the `while` loop?  Can you please provide a code example as to what the `while(true)` loop is doing?  This question feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and a consequence of the current design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch exceptions in the worker thread, save them into a queue variable that is shared by the two threads, and check that queue periodically in the main thread.

To use a queue, you need to first convert your exceptions to a common type. You can use `std::exception` or `string` or whatever is the best for your situation. If you absolutely need to keep information of the original exception class, you can use [boost::exception_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html).

Variables you need (these could be members of `AsioThread`):

```
boost::mutex queueMutex;
std::queue<exceptionType> exceptionQueue;
```

Run this function in the worker thread:

```
void AsioThread::RunIoService(){
    try{
        ioService.run();
    }
    catch(const exceptionType& e){
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> queueMutex;
        exceptionQueue.push(e);
    }
    catch(...){
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> queueMutex;
        exceptionQueue.push(exceptionType("unknown exception"));
    }
}
```

Launch the worker thread like this:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&AsioThread::RunIoService, this));
t.detach();
```

In the main thread:

```
while(true){
    // Do something

    // Handle exceptions from the worker thread
    bool hasException = false;
    exceptionType newestException;
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> queueMutex;
        if(!exceptionQueue.empty()){
            hasException = true;
            newestException = exceptionQueue.front();
            exceptionQueue.pop();
        }
    }
    if(hasException){    
        // Do something with the exception
    }
}
```

[This blog post](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) implements a thread-safe queue, which you can use to simplify saving exceptions; in that case you would not need a separate mutex because that would be inside the queue class.

Comment: It´s a good idea, but I did not coded the working thread... It is handled by `boost::asio`. See `boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));`above...

Comment: @Mendes While you may not have control over `io_service::run()`, you do have control over the thread's entry point.  Consider creating a function that invokes `io_service.run()` within a try/catch block, propagating exceptions as needed, and specifying this function as the thread entry point.

Comment: @Mendes I changed my answer, it should now work in your situation.